NSManagedObjectContext refreshObject:mergeChange: registers spurious undo
In my core data Mac app, I'd like to free memory by turning unused managed objects into faults, using NSManagedObjectContext's refreshObject:mergeChange:NO. I'm sending that message to the "view context" of the app, which has an undo manager.
Sending the above message to the context generates an undo action that becomes visible in the Edit menu (a simple "Undo" that cannot be redone). I suppose the change in the context (turning objects into faults) is captured by its undo manager. But this is not a user action, and the objects aren't actually modified.
I suppose I could just disable undo registration during the operation, but I wonder if I'm doing something wrong as I haven't seen mentioned anywhere that refreshObject:mergeChange: generates undo actions.
This "issue" can be reproduced with a very simple core data app containing a single entity (I tested this).
(I have another issue where some objects are inappropriately turned into faults by core data (not by my code), which also generates undo actions. So I guess this is not avoidable.)
